# identify / fingerprint a Windows Server core installation versus full

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, windows-server-2008-r2, powershell, wmi

Seems like this should be easy, but I am not finding any information on how to remotely identify a Windows Server "core" installation as such, via WMI, Powershell or other method that can query lots of machines relatively quickly. I am trying to report on the percentage of servers we have running a core versus a full installation. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this question was last answered, the previous technique no longer works. Based on another post [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/529124), the quickest and most reliable technique to identify core installations is to look for the presence of Windows Explorer executable. It will be missing on server core instances:

```
Test-Path "$env:windir\explorer.exe"
```

Answer (score 8):

```
Get-WmiObject -Query "Select OperatingSystemSKU from Win32_OperatingSystem"
```

You'll need to convert the response to Hex to compare:

- 0C Datacenter (core installation)
- 27 Server Datacenter without Hyper-V (core installation)
- 0E Server Enterprise (core installation)
- 29 Server Enterprise without Hyper-V (core installation)
- 2A Microsoft Hyper-V Server
- 0D Server Standard (core installation)
- 28 Server Standard without Hyper-V (core installation)
- 1D Web Server(core installation)

Table is based on info from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724358.aspx

Comment: This doesn't seem to work anymore. The result is always 7.

Comment: There is an updated question with a better answer posted here: http://serverfault.com/questions/529124